# How can I define submenus in a PopoverMenu with GJS?

Tags: gtk3, gjs

[Documentation says:](https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/gtk30%7E3.0/gtk.popovermenu)

> `GtkPopoverMenu` is a subclass of `Gtk.Popover` that treats its
> children like menus and allows switching between them. [...]
>
> To add a child as a submenu, set the `#GtkPopoverMenu:submenu`
> child property to the name of the submenu.

I don't really understand how I should set submenus here: `PopoverMenu` has no attribute names `submenu` and it also appears to accept only a single widget as `child`. Every example of usage I see is in XML, which makes me think that this can not be define programmatically.

Please note: I'm using GTK3. I don't want to "import" from a `MenuModel`.

Comment: FYI, "child properties" aren't covered in the gobject-introspection data model, which is part of the reason why they have been replaced by regular properties and other kinds of API starting in GTK 4.

Answer (score 1):

Just found it by myself: [`Container#child_set_property(icon, property_name, value)`](https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/gtk30%7E3.0/gtk.container#method-child_set_property)

Example of usage:

```
myPopOverMenu.add(child1);
myPopOverMenu.child_set_property(child1, "submenu", "main");
myPopOverMenu.add(child2);
myPopOverMenu.child_set_property(child2, "submenu", "some_menu");
```